How to get requirements from my Airflow python environment
How to perform pip freeze > requirements.txt for Airflow environment?
Or get list of packages by another way.
Airflow v. 2.8.2 installed with Docker.

$ docker run apache/airflow:2.8.2 bash -c "pip freeze" > requirements.txt
$ cat requirements.txt

# result:
adal==1.2.7
adlfs==2024.2.0
aiobotocore==2.11.2
aiofiles==23.2.1
aiohttp==3.9.3
aioitertools==0.11.0
aiosignal==1.3.1
alembic==1.13.1
amqp==5.2.0
anyio==4.3.0
apache-airflow==2.8.2
apache-airflow-providers-amazon==8.18.0
apache-airflow-providers-celery==3.6.0
apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes==8.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-common-io==1.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql==1.11.0
apache-airflow-providers-docker==3.9.1
apache-airflow-providers-elasticsearch==5.3.3
apache-airflow-providers-ftp==3.7.0
apache-airflow-providers-google==10.15.0
apache-airflow-providers-grpc==3.4.1
apache-airflow-providers-hashicorp==3.6.3
apache-airflow-providers-http==4.9.1
apache-airflow-providers-imap==3.5.0
apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure==9.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-mysql==5.5.3
apache-airflow-providers-odbc==4.4.1
apache-airflow-providers-openlineage==1.5.0
apache-airflow-providers-postgres==5.10.1
apache-airflow-providers-redis==3.6.0
apache-airflow-providers-sendgrid==3.4.0
apache-airflow-providers-sftp==4.9.0
apache-airflow-providers-slack==8.6.1
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==5.3.1
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite==3.7.1
apache-airflow-providers-ssh==3.10.1
apispec==6.4.0
argcomplete==3.2.2
asgiref==3.7.2
asn1crypto==1.5.1
async-timeout==4.0.3
asyncssh==2.14.2
attrs==23.2.0
Authlib==1.3.0
azure-batch==14.1.0
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.30.0
azure-cosmos==4.5.1
azure-datalake-store==0.0.53
azure-identity==1.15.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.8.0
azure-kusto-data==4.3.1
azure-mgmt-containerinstance==10.1.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry==10.3.0
azure-mgmt-core==1.4.0
azure-mgmt-cosmosdb==9.4.0
azure-mgmt-datafactory==5.0.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg==3.0.1
azure-mgmt-datalake-store==0.5.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-mgmt-resource==23.0.1
azure-mgmt-storage==21.1.0
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-servicebus==7.11.4
azure-storage-blob==12.19.0
azure-storage-file-datalake==12.14.0
azure-storage-file-share==12.15.0
azure-synapse-artifacts==0.18.0
azure-synapse-spark==0.7.0
Babel==2.14.0
backoff==2.2.1
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
bcrypt==4.1.2
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
billiard==4.2.0
blinker==1.7.0
boto3==1.33.13
botocore==1.33.13
cachelib==0.9.0
cachetools==5.3.2
cattrs==23.2.3
celery==5.3.6
certifi==2024.2.2
cffi==1.16.0
chardet==5.2.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.3.0
clickclick==20.10.2
colorama==0.4.6
colorlog==4.8.0
ConfigUpdater==3.2
connexion==2.14.2
cron-descriptor==1.4.3
croniter==2.0.1
cryptography==41.0.7
db-dtypes==1.2.0
decorator==5.1.1
Deprecated==1.2.14
dill==0.3.1.1
distlib==0.3.8
dnspython==2.6.1
docker==7.0.0
docutils==0.20.1
elastic-transport==8.12.0
elasticsearch==8.12.1
email-validator==1.3.1
eventlet==0.35.2
exceptiongroup==1.2.0
filelock==3.13.1
Flask==2.2.5
Flask-AppBuilder==4.3.11
Flask-Babel==2.0.0
Flask-Caching==2.1.0
Flask-JWT-Extended==4.6.0
Flask-Limiter==3.5.1
Flask-Login==0.6.3
Flask-Session==0.5.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==1.2.1
flower==2.0.1
frozenlist==1.4.1
fsspec==2024.2.0
gcloud-aio-auth==4.2.3
gcloud-aio-bigquery==7.1.0
gcloud-aio-storage==9.2.0
gcsfs==2024.2.0
gevent==24.2.1
google-ads==23.1.0
google-analytics-admin==0.22.6
google-api-core==2.17.1
google-api-python-client==2.119.0
google-auth==2.28.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.2.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.2.0
google-cloud-aiplatform==1.42.1
google-cloud-appengine-logging==1.4.2
google-cloud-audit-log==0.2.5
google-cloud-automl==2.13.2
google-cloud-batch==0.17.12
google-cloud-bigquery==3.17.2
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer==3.15.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.24.0
google-cloud-bigtable==2.23.0
google-cloud-build==3.23.2
google-cloud-compute==1.17.0
google-cloud-container==2.41.0
google-cloud-core==2.4.1
google-cloud-datacatalog==3.18.2
google-cloud-dataflow-client==0.8.9
google-cloud-dataform==0.5.8
google-cloud-dataplex==1.12.2
google-cloud-dataproc==5.9.2
google-cloud-dataproc-metastore==1.15.2
google-cloud-dlp==3.15.2
google-cloud-kms==2.21.2
google-cloud-language==2.13.2
google-cloud-logging==3.9.0
google-cloud-memcache==1.9.2
google-cloud-monitoring==2.19.2
google-cloud-orchestration-airflow==1.12.0
google-cloud-os-login==2.14.2
google-cloud-pubsub==2.19.6
google-cloud-redis==2.15.2
google-cloud-resource-manager==1.12.2
google-cloud-run==0.10.4
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.18.2
google-cloud-spanner==3.42.0
google-cloud-speech==2.25.0
google-cloud-storage==2.14.0
google-cloud-storage-transfer==1.11.2
google-cloud-tasks==2.16.2
google-cloud-texttospeech==2.16.2
google-cloud-translate==3.15.2
google-cloud-videointelligence==2.13.2
google-cloud-vision==3.7.1
google-cloud-workflows==1.14.2
google-crc32c==1.5.0
google-re2==1.1
google-resumable-media==2.7.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.62.0
graphviz==0.20.1
greenlet==3.0.3
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.13.0
grpc-interceptor==0.15.4
grpcio==1.62.0
grpcio-gcp==0.2.2
grpcio-status==1.62.0
gunicorn==21.2.0
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==0.16.3
httplib2==0.22.0
httpx==0.23.3
humanize==4.9.0
hvac==2.1.0
idna==3.6
ijson==3.2.3
importlib-metadata==6.11.0
importlib-resources==5.13.0
inflection==0.5.1
isodate==0.6.1
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.3
jmespath==0.10.0
json-merge-patch==0.2
jsonpath-ng==1.6.1
jsonschema==4.21.1
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
kombu==5.3.5
kubernetes==29.0.0
kubernetes_asyncio==29.0.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.10.0
ldap3==2.9.1
limits==3.9.0
linkify-it-py==2.0.3
lockfile==0.12.2
looker-sdk==24.2.0
lxml==5.1.0
Mako==1.3.2
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
marshmallow==3.20.2
marshmallow-oneofschema==3.1.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.26.1
mdit-py-plugins==0.4.0
mdurl==0.1.2
more-itertools==10.2.0
msal==1.27.0
msal-extensions==1.1.0
msrest==0.7.1
msrestazure==0.6.4
multidict==6.0.5
mysql-connector-python==8.3.0
mysqlclient==2.2.4
numpy==1.24.4
oauthlib==3.2.2
openlineage-integration-common==1.9.0
openlineage-python==1.9.0
openlineage_sql==1.9.0
opentelemetry-api==1.23.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp==1.23.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-common==1.23.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc==1.23.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-http==1.23.0
opentelemetry-proto==1.23.0
opentelemetry-sdk==1.23.0
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions==0.44b0
ordered-set==4.1.0
packaging==23.2
pandas==2.0.3
pandas-gbq==0.21.0
paramiko==3.4.0
pathspec==0.12.1
pendulum==3.0.0
pkgutil_resolve_name==1.3.10
platformdirs==3.11.0
pluggy==1.4.0
ply==3.11
portalocker==2.8.2
prison==0.2.1
prometheus_client==0.20.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.43
proto-plus==1.23.0
protobuf==4.25.3
psutil==5.9.8
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
pyarrow==14.0.2
pyasn1==0.5.1
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
PyAthena==3.3.0
pycparser==2.21
pydata-google-auth==1.8.2
Pygments==2.17.2
PyJWT==2.8.0
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pyodbc==5.1.0
pyOpenSSL==24.0.0
pyparsing==3.1.1
python-daemon==3.0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.1
python-http-client==3.3.7
python-ldap==3.4.4
python-nvd3==0.15.0
python-slugify==8.0.4
pytz==2024.1
PyYAML==6.0.1
redis==4.6.0
redshift-connector==2.1.0
referencing==0.33.0
requests==2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
requests-toolbelt==1.0.0
rfc3339-validator==0.1.4
rfc3986==1.5.0
rich==13.7.0
rich-argparse==1.4.0
rpds-py==0.18.0
rsa==4.9
s3transfer==0.8.2
scramp==1.4.4
sendgrid==6.11.0
setproctitle==1.3.3
shapely==2.0.3
six==1.16.0
slack_sdk==3.27.0
sniffio==1.3.0
snowflake-connector-python==3.7.1
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.5.1
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.5
SQLAlchemy==1.4.51
sqlalchemy-bigquery==1.9.0
SQLAlchemy-JSONField==1.0.2
sqlalchemy-redshift==0.8.14
sqlalchemy-spanner==1.6.2
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.41.1
sqlparse==0.4.4
sshtunnel==0.4.0
starkbank-ecdsa==2.2.0
statsd==4.0.1
tabulate==0.9.0
tenacity==8.2.3
termcolor==2.4.0
text-unidecode==1.3
time-machine==2.13.0
tomlkit==0.12.3
tornado==6.4
typing_extensions==4.9.0
tzdata==2024.1
uc-micro-py==1.0.3
unicodecsv==0.14.1
universal-pathlib==0.1.4
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.18
vine==5.1.0
virtualenv==20.25.1
watchtower==3.0.1
wcwidth==0.2.13
websocket-client==1.7.0
Werkzeug==2.2.3
wrapt==1.16.0
WTForms==3.1.2
yarl==1.9.4
zipp==3.17.0
zope.event==5.0
zope.interface==6.2

Or for active container:
docker exec {CONTAINER_NAME} bash -c "pip freeze"

